# How to install a tizen wearable app (wgt) through an android app written in C# (Xamarin)?

Tags: c#, android, deployment, tizen-wearable-sdk

I have seen many examples in android application written in java, but I have yet to see one example using xamarin. I tried following [Use the Accessory SDK in Android](http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/creating-your-first-app/native-companion/use-accessory) from Samsung docs, but I got stuck on the part of making a class extend from SAAgent as I found no C# Samsung Accessory SDK.

Comment: If you have a '.wgt' or '.tpk' file, You can directly install it on Tizen wearable. No Job for Java & C# here.

Comment: I know how to install it directly into the Tizen wearable. My question is how to install the wearable through an android app. Yes its a job for Java and I hoped that there was one available in c#.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung Accessory SDK is for Java only, it's not for C#.

Tizen .NET using Xamarin.Forms is only available for Tizen Mobile & Tizen TV now.

Hope, Tizen .NET for wearables plan comes soon.

Comment: I am not looking to make a project for the wearable in C#/Xamarin.Forms. I have the app ready, but I guess as you said, there is no way available yet for c# to deploy the wearable app from the mobile app since their SDK is just for Java.